# Compare to with String in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, compareto

I have just checked some cases with CompareTo method of String as below:

```
  print("case 1>>>>> ");
  print("02 Dec 2022".compareTo("24 Nov 2022"));

  print("case 2>>>>> ");
  print("24 Nov 2022".compareTo("24 Nov 2022"));

  print("case 3>>>>> ");
  print("23 Nov 2022".compareTo("24 Nov 2022"));
```

For case 2, it returned value **0**
For case 1 and case 3 It returned value **-1**

Why it is returning value **-1** for both case 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find on [compareTo](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Comparable/compareTo.html)

> ... it returns a negative integer if this is ordered before other, a positive integer if this is ordered after other, and zero if this and other are ordered together.

The *case 1 and 3* are, this is ordered before other.

For case 2, this and other are ordered together.

Comment: btw the format  `this.compareTo(other)`

Comment: can you please explain What ordered means?

Comment: like for 1st case, `02` is before `24`, and for case two both are same

Comment: means print("25 Dec 2022".compareTo("24 Nov 2022")); will return 1 ?